# How do you access your computer's menu bar in java?

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

I am making a GUI Text Editor in Java. I know Java's swing interface provides menu bars in the form of JMenuBars, but I want something that doesn't take up that much space in the window.

[Picture that shows a JMenuBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLDJM.png)

I know this is good enough, but I want something that looks like this:

[Picture that shows my computer's menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zt98.png)

Is there a way to do this programmatically? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so just simply have to code it by hand. with all the JMenuItems etc.

Comment: Your computer's menu is platform specific, so odds are you will have to do it yourself...

Comment: Unless you're willing to make your own window look and feel delegate which can provide this functionality, it's not possible to do using Swing

Comment: i think your program font style depends on configuration, java version, eclipse version etc.i had same problem with windows platform,netbens and jdk 1.4.
use any synthetica look and feel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create title bar menu in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108272/how-can-i-create-title-bar-menu-in-java)